# Vaadin grid filtering with HashMap (no class)

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin-grid

I have worked with Vaadin Grids before based on classes (e.g. person as shown in most examples made on Vaadins-website). However, for my next project, I need one based on a HashMap (or any non-class-based variable).

So now, I have a working Vaadin Grid based on a HashMap<String, String>. But I am coming up short when I have to add the filter-methods.

So here is my full code.

```
public class TestGrid extends Div {
List<String> columns;

public TestGrid() {
    Grid<HashMap<String, String>> grid = new Grid<>();
    columns = new ArrayList<>();

    grid.appendHeaderRow();
    HeaderRow headerRow = grid.appendHeaderRow();

    grid.setItems(getItems());

    for (String s : columns) {
        TextField textField = new TextField();
        grid.addColumn(h -> h.get(s)).setHeader(s);

        TextField filter = new TextField();
        filter.setSizeFull();
        filter.setClearButtonVisible(true);
        filter.setValueChangeMode(ValueChangeMode.EAGER);
        filter.addValueChangeListener(event -> {

        });
        headerRow.getCell(grid.getColumns().get(grid.getColumns().size() - 1)).setComponent(filter);
    }

    add(grid);
}

List<HashMap<String, String>> getItems() {
    columns = new ArrayList<>();
    columns.add("Row1");
    columns.add("Row2");
    columns.add("Row3");
    columns.add("Row4");
    columns.add("Row5");

    List<HashMap<String, String>> hashMaps = new ArrayList<>();

    while (hashMaps.size() != 10) {
        HashMap<String, String> item = new HashMap<>();
        for (String s : columns) {
            item.put(s, RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(10));
        }
        hashMaps.add(item);
    }
    return hashMaps;
}
}
```

Normally, I would have a dataprovider and a second class (gridfilter) with setters, getters, and the filter-boolean. Like so:

```
        if (name != null && name.length() > 0 && !StringUtils
            .containsIgnoreCase(String.valueOf(user.getName()),
                    name)) {
        return false;
    }
```

But now that it works on the HashMap<String, String> I am wondering how to proceed.

I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 2):

Set ids to the filter fields and then use it to retrieve the correct value from the map? Something like (where event is the ValueChangeEvent from the filter field)

```
if (filter!= null && filter.length() > 0 && !StringUtils
            .containsIgnoreCase(map.get(event.getSource().getId()),
                    filter)) {
        return false;
}
```